# Path homotopy between loops

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We have two loops $f$ , $g$, one loop based at $x$ and the other at $y$ respectively. We also have a path $h$ with initial point $x$ and end point $y$. I'm trying to find a path homotopy between $f$ and $h$ * $g$ * $\overline{h}$. We also have that $f,g$ are free homotopic. Obviously $f$ and $h$ * $g$ * $\overline{h}$ are based at $x$ and I know I'm supposed to use the free homotopy condition to find the path-homotopy, but I'm totally stuck. Any hints or help would be much appreciated

Comment: This doesn't have to be true. If you're allowed to choose $h$, then it will in fact be true, but you should clarify if that's the statement you're looking for.

Comment: I think that $h$ is just a path starting at $x$ and ending at $y$, thats what the exercise says

Comment: Is the exercise "for *any* path from $x$ to $y$, blah" or "there exists a path from $x$ to $y$ such that blah" ? The first one is wrong; and the second one is true but it's not the question you have asked - although I believe it is what the exercise is meant to be

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I'll be true regardless of $h$ as long as $h$ goes from $x$ to $y$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma no - take $x=y$ and $h$ the trivial path, this is claiming that free homotopic loops are homotopic

Comment: So Chris, you interpret $f \ast g$ as going from left to right: first $f$ then $g$?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi "there exists a path..." and from that I'm trying to explicitely state the path homotopy between the loops, having in mind of course that $f$ and $g$ are free homotopic

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what do you mean? I dont use the concatenation between $f$ and $g$ anywhere

Comment: You use $h \ast g \ast \bar{h}$ though...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes thats going from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarification from the comments that $h$ is *not* fixed, here's a **hint** :

Let $H$ be a free homotopy of loops from $f$ to $g$. Consider the path $h$ from $x$ to $y$ given by $t\mapsto H(0,t)$. Do a drawing to see why that path might work, and then try to prove it.

(where $H(-,0) = f, H(-,1) = g$)

Note : if $h$ is required to be fixed, the result is wrong. For instance, take $x=y$ and $h$ to be the trivial path. Then you would be claiming that any freely homotopic loops are homotopic, which is known not to be true. That's why you have to somehow cook up an appropriate path $h$, and the free homotopy that you've assumed existed allows you to do that.

Added: here's a sketch of proof. You want to define a homotopy $H'$ based on $H$ but using the path $h$. At time $s$, $H'$ is the path that follows $h$ up until $s$, then follows $H(-,s)$, and then $h$ in the reverse direction.

You should try to make that more precise, prove that it's well-defined, continuous, and a path-homotopy between the appropriate things.

Comment: Do I have to define a specific path in order to find the path homotopy?

Comment: Well if you don't even know who $h$ is, how are you going to prove that $f$ and $hg\overline h$ are homotopic ? (you shouldn't accept answers if you're not fully satisfied, i.e. if you haven't solved your question ;) )

Comment: Could you elaborate more, I tried it but I still dont get how the path homotopy would arise from this

Comment: Have you tried making a drawing to get an idea of how it can go?

Comment: So where does $g$ fit into all of this? Do I have to use composites anywhere?

Comment: How does this $H'(s,1)$ = $h$ * $g$ * $ \overline{h}$

Comment: $g$ is the endpath of $H$. At time $s=1$, $H'$ follows all of $h$, then $H(-,1) = g$, then $h$ in the other direction

Comment: So how do we denote that? As the composite of $h$ , $H(-,1)$ and $\overline{h}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the definition !

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry if I was annoying but I'm self studying algebraic topology and sometimes obvious things seem too difficult

Comment: Don't apologize ! :) I was also trying not to give you the complete answer as that wouldn't help you make actual progress. Note that I haven't filled out all the details, and that it would be instructive to do so